# ASP.NET MVC filtering pagedlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with pagedList.

I have a task to make a view with filter panel and paged list.

My views:

Index:
This is the main view

```
@model WebUI.Areas.Admin.Models.Product.ProductSearchViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#filter">@Resources.Lang.Filter</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="filter" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ProductsList", "Product", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "productsList" }, new { @id = "searchForm", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
                {
                   // some items to filter
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="productsList" class="row">
// Here will be rendered partial view with pagedList
</div>
```

Partial view with pagedList

```
@using PagedList.Mvc
@model PagedList.IPagedList<WebUI.Models.Product.RegularProductDomainModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("_ProductSummary", item)
}

Страница @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) из @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("ProductsList", page = page}),
    PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "productsList" }))
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProductsList(ProductSearchViewModel model, int page = 1, int pageSize = 5)
{
      using (_unitOfWork = _factory.Create())
      {
    // prepare list of items

var products = _unitOfWork.ProductsRepository.GetProducts(model.CategoryID, model.BrandID,   model.ProductStateID,null,true, model.Code)
                                .ToPagedList(page, pageSize);
                            return PartialView("_ProductsList", products);
     }
}
```

Filtering is working great. But if I want to filter values and then do paging it doesn't work, because when I click paging, in controller I have my ProductSearchViewModel ***only with default values***. As I understand It doesn't work, because my PartialView doesn't know anything about ProductSearchViewModel, which is used as in Index.chtml. Is there any way to pass my ProductSearchViewModel to controller when I do paging?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible solutions...

1.) Pass the ProductSearchViewModel (or the values from it) into the partial view, so you can then pass it on into the pager helper from there. This could be achieved either by creating a new ViewModel which contains the ProductSearchViewModel as well as your Paged List, or simply placing into ViewData before returning the view.

2.) Move the paging to the main view (Index) so you can pass the ProductSearchViewModel along with the page number.